# Prompt = background image javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, roblox

Im trying to do that the **background-image: url("+person.value+");** inside **bg1** is the prompt value but idk how it just remove the background when i try

```
     document.getElementsByClassName("btn-cta-md")[0].addEventListener("click",
  function(){ 
    var person = prompt("image url: (.png, .jpg, .gif) example:", "https://skully.com/image.png");
    if (person != null) {
      var bg1=`


      <style id="bgimage" class="texture" type="text/css">.avatar-back
      {
        background-image: url('+person.Value+');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
      }</style>`;
          console.log(person);
      
       document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail-2d-container avatar-card-image')[0].innerHTML += bg1
   
    }
  }
);
```

Thanks for any help i have been trying for the 4 past hours and i can't think of a way anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in a template string so just use interpolation like this:

```
background-image: url('${person}');
```

Comment: Replace your background-image with mine

Comment: OH MY GOD IT WAS THAT THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Also i got another question if you can help me how would i go about saving this ( if the page refresh/close it save the background set in the prompt for the next time )

Comment: That's another topic, you have to save the state in some browser storage like localStorage or IndexedDB